# Css "right" minus value without extending scroll area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have 2 sidebars aligned to right where one is hidden. I want that when user clicks one button from right sidebar, the sidebar should disappear to right and a new sidebar should come at the same moment with css animatons.

If I use `right:-50px` this extends scrollable area.  If I use a container with width, this still extends scrollable area.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/oz62o2yd/2/ <- this is just right minus value, coming to screen area.

and http://jsfiddle.net/oz62o2yd/3 <- and here I use a container, but that doesnt stop page from making scrollbars.

I dont want to just "hide" scrollbars but also disable them.

If I need to use javascript for this, I'm also OK with that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oz62o2yd/3/  <- here is the second link I meant to post but couldnt due to the fact I have 1 rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using

```
window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0); };
```

Thing is, I was using webgl/three.js and three.js, when fullscreen has a very small border at bottom of screen in some(most) resolutions. To fix that border, you had to display:block and when you have display:block with other elements and tons of position absolutes, width:100% meant that canvas was going to "second page"

the "overflow:hidden" on body tag and/or container works on IE11, but not on chrome/canary/nightly and familiar browsers because of complex structure(very complex, btw), and because the same page had jQuery UI this also meant that if I want to show a dialog on page start-up, the "container" wouldnt be containing all elements as jQuery UI created elements in body tag, so it also meant I had to edit jQuery(which is OK)

the js tag above works flawless in all modern browsers but snappy in old ones which I'm not targeting.

Answer (score 1):

The document size of the browser will always grow as required to the right and bottom, due to the nature of flow-based layout. Therefore rendering something 'beyond the right border' will indeed cause the scrollbars to the right.

Depending on your exact situation, multiple solutions may apply. The easiest is simply disabling overflow horizontally:

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Which will actually [fix your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oz62o2yd/4/). For more complex cases it might not suffice. You could then elect to wrap the offending element in an absolutely positioned parent, which stays within the existing bounds and has limited `overflow` settings itself.

Comment: This doesnt work for me, it hides the scrollbars but you can still scroll by middle clicking on page. What are other solutions?